# If $AB$ is a symmetric matrix, is $BA$ still symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $AB$ is a symmetric matrix, is $BA$ still symmetric? The matrices are not communative.

Comment: in general no, for example take $A$ as a rectangular matrix and $B$ it's right pseudoinverse.

Comment: Even if A and B are symmetric themselves, this is true if they commute, because then $BA=AB$.

Comment: In fact, for square symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ we have $AB$ symmetric if and only if $AB = BA$.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}^T,\\
\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&1}\ne\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&1}^T.
\end{align}